# dotnet highcharts - how to enable scrollbar

Tags: .net, highcharts

How to enable scrollbar in dotnet highcharts .?

Meaning how to add the below js configuration in dotnet chart configuration in c# code.?

scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
},

Comment: Scrollbar is available only in highstock, not in highcharts.

Comment: That's not an answer Seb! Quite happy to use Highstock!